# Why the function cannot achieve the expected result?

Tags: programming

Today, I write a toy code (*Framed the prime in a list*) to practice *Mathematica programming* ,which as shown below:

**Trail 1:**

```
(Framed@# /; PrimeQ@# &) /@ Range[10]
```

> [image]

**Trail 2:**

```
(Framed@x_ /; PrimeQ@x) /@ Range[10]
```

> [image]

**Trail 3:**

```
framedPrime[x_] := Framed@x /; PrimeQ@x;
framedPrime[x_] := x
framedPrime /@ Range[10]
```

> Achieving the ideal result

**Trail 4:**

```
If[PrimeQ@#, Framed[#], #] & /@ Range[20]
```

> Achieving the ideal result

**Trail 5:**

```
Range[5] /. # :> Framed@# /; PrimeQ@# &
```

> [image]

**Trial 6:**

```
Range[20] /. x_ :> Framed@x /; PrimeQ@x
```

> Achieving the ideal result

So I'd like to know why *`trial 1,2,5`,(what's the difference between trial 5 and 6?)* were failed.(Although I used *Mathematica* for progrmming for a year)

Comment: The syntax for `/;` is `pattern /; test` or `something deferred /; test`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overall, I think your main confusion stems from mixing up different the programming paradigms and syntax in Mathematica. The way [Functional](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html) and [Rule & Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RulesAndPatterns.html) based programming works is different.

To quote the [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProceduralProgramming.html):

> The Wolfram Language stands out from traditional computer languages in
>   supporting many programming paradigms.

In particular:
Trials 1 and 2 are using [Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (`patt/;test`) in the wrong way. Condition is used to conditionally apply a replacement rule by further restricting a pattern, while you are using it in a purely functional setting. You correctly used the functional syntax in Trial 4.
In Trial 5 you are also mixing functional and pattern matching / replacement rule structures. In that code, you are trying to match expressions to [`Slot[1]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) (`#`). It also has the problem that [`&`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) is very loosely binding, so the whole expression is interpreted as a pure function. You correctly used the replacement syntax and patterns in Trial 6.
Trial 3 is essentially like Trial 6 since it uses rules and patterns, but it uses `SetDelayed` to an assignment that tries to apply that rule to all expressions.

For more info (beyond the documentation links above) on the different programming paradigms available in Mathematica see:
[Appendix A](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node66.html) of Leonid Shifrin's book: [Mathematica Programming: An advanced introduction](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/);   and
[Programming Paradigms via Mathematica (A First Course)](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1847/).

Answer (score 2):

I post this to illustrate some of the ways you could do this task. I have voted for Simon's answer, however, as it addresses the 'why' (the point of the question and the most important point).

```
f[x_?PrimeQ] := Framed[x];
f[x_] := x;
g[x_] := Framed[x] /; PrimeQ@x;
g[x_] := x;
h[x_] := Piecewise[{{Framed[x], PrimeQ@x}, {x, True}}];
j[x_] := Which[PrimeQ@x, Framed@x, ! PrimeQ@x, x];
k[x_] := If[PrimeQ@x, Framed[x], x];
m[x_] := x /. {a_?PrimeQ -> Framed[a]};
n[x_] := Switch[PrimeQ@x, True, Framed[x], False, x];
```

or the ugly

```
p[x_] := With[{pos = Position[x, _?PrimeQ]}, 
  ReplacePart[x, Thread[pos -> Framed /@ Extract[x, pos]]]]
```

Then:

```
f /@ Range[10]
g /@ Range[10]
h /@ Range[10]
j /@ Range[10]
k /@ Range[10]
m@Range[10]
n /@ Range[10]
p@Range[10]
```

[image]